# How to run a user desktop application from a debian package post-install script?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, debian-based

I've created a debian package (for ubuntu 16.04). The package installs a .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart, so that the application will start when a user logs on, and for all users.
But I'd also need to start that application immediately in the current session, i.e. the session of the user that initiated the installation of the package. I need to avoid that the user must log off and on again.
Can this be done from inside a postinst script?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm in exactly the same spot and I can only think of pretty ugly hacks, such as grepping `who` for the user currently logged into the current `$DISPLAY`.

Comment: Yes I found a solution but very hacky indeed. Don’t have access to it now though. If you like I’ll look it up later